# Incrementing member of struct segfaults

Tags: c, memory, struct, segmentation-fault, malloc

I'm trying to increment a value of a struct (an int) just to test a code snippet of mine (This isn't my entire code), just the point of focus of my question. I'm given the struct:

```
typedef struct Test Test;
typedef struct Test {
    char * name;
    int numOfElements;
    Test * test[];
}Test;
```

As well as the functions:

```
void startFunc(Test ** newStruct) {

    newStruct = malloc(sizeof(Test));

    (*newStruct)->name = NULL;
    (*newStruct)->numOfElements = 0;

    func(newStruct);

}

void func(Test ** newStruct) {

    (*newStruct)->numOfElements++;

}

//create function to later free allocated memory
```

However incrementing the value of numOfElements seems to segfault. Is it the fact that I didn't allocate enough memory (Since I'm using a flexible array member?)

I tried using valgrind and got a invalid read of size 8 on the `(*newStruct)->name =NULL;`

Which would suggest it's not malloced, Memory help here would be much appreciated,

Comment: So I have to malloc both the double pointer and single pointer? I have a function (not shown here) which receives a double pointer arguement, so I wasn't so sure.

Comment: I've edited my code to accurately display the function header I'm given (I'm forced to use double pointers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`malloc(sizeof(Test))` is intended to allocate a raw object of type `Test`, so conceptually it returns a `Test *` pointer. This pointer is assigned to `newStruct`, which is a `Test **`. This mismatch between `Test *` and `Test **` already suggests that the `malloc` line is broken.

An immediate guess would be that this

```
newStruct = malloc(sizeof(Test));
```

was actually intended to be

```
*newStruct = malloc(sizeof(Test));
```

You are already scrupulously using `*newStruct` everywhere in your `startFunc`, but for some reason completely forgetting about it in the `malloc` line.

An arguably better way to express the same thing would be

```
*newStruct = malloc(sizeof **newStruct);
```

Comment: And as a matter of style, I always introduce a single-pointer for local use, and assign to the double pointer just before return. It helps avoid confusing issues like this.